# Access a property of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, reflection, wpf-controls, custom-controls, ienumerable

I have a custom class for a combobox having following properties:

```
public IEnumerable<object> ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }
}

public string DisplayMemberPath
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value); }
}
```

where `ItemsSourceProperty,DisplayMemberPathProperty` are the dependency properties already registered.

Now if `ItemSource` has a list of custom objects :{id int, name string}. and DisplayMemberPath has value:'name' or 'id'. How can I access 'name' or 'id' properties of my object ?
       `

Comment: Please read the help available for the editor to improve the formatting of your post in future. Now, it's not clear what you mean by "my object" - you've got a whole sequence of objects there... you really need to give more context here. (A short but complete example would be ideal...)

Comment: Given: IEnumerable<object> and a property of that object. e.g if the IEnumerable contains objects of type A having a,b as its properties.Also given the name of property which we want to access ,say e.g 'a'. Then I would need list containing all values of property 'a'

Comment: like e.g foreach(item in ItemSource) { mylist.Add(item.DisplayMemberPath) }

Comment: But you don't know the type at compile-time, right? Do you definitely need to do this yourself rather than let WPF sort it out for you? Basically I suspect you'll need to call `GetType()` on each element, then `GetProperty`...

Comment: @JonSkeet : Is the explanation sufficient?

Comment: Not really, to be honest... but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes you got it right , I dont know the type at compile-time. Can you let me know how to do it with help of reflection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not entirely clear why you need to do this binding yourself (when WPF does a lot of this for you), but this might work:

```
foreach (object item in ItemsSource)
{
    var property = item.GetType().GetProperty(DisplayMemberPath);
    var value = property.GetValue(item, null);
    // Use the value here
}
```

Note that this will be pretty slow, and will only handle a single property name (rather than a full path). There are more complex alternatives which would perform better, but I'd probably go with the simplest approach first.